# How to prevent google to parse my calendar?

Tags: privacy

I use Android 6.0.1 on a Samsung Galaxy J5.

I have my own mail + contacts + calendar server on a dedicated server.

I noticed that when I put some entrys in my calendar (smartphone) with an address, when I open Waze, I have the choice proposed directly (Appointment) to go to this address.

I don't want google to track my calendar, so any idea to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, install Xprivacy for rooted devices.